# Expression of $\int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}}\, e^{-i\left<v,\omega\right>}\,d\sigma(\omega) = ?$

Tags: integration, analysis, reference-request, special-functions, bessel-functions

I would like to know what the following integral equals
$$\int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}}\, e^{-i\left<v,\omega\right>}\,d\sigma(\omega) = ?,$$
where $S^{n-1}$ is the two-dimentional sphere of $\mathbb R^n$.

Otherwise, if there is a reference, I would be very grateful. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: I assume $S^{n - 1}$ is the unit $(n - 1)$-dimensional sphere centered at the origin. Take spherical coordinates s.t. the first angle is zero for $v$, then $v \cdot w = |v| \cos \theta$,
$$I = S_{n - 2} \int_0^\pi e^{-i |v| \cos \theta} \sin^{n - 2} \theta \, d\theta = \\
\sqrt \pi \hspace {1.5px} S_{n - 2} \hspace {1.5px}
 \Gamma {\left( \frac {n - 1} 2 \right)}
 \left( \frac 2 {|v|} \right)^{n/2 - 1} J_{n/2 - 1}(|v|).$$

Comment: Thank you Maxim